# NullPointerException.. My favourite

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, minecraft, bukkit

**EDIT: I would just like to apologize for my simple mistake.. I'm only 12 :P**

I seem to be having the great NullPointerException.. I'm using the Bukkit API, just in case that changed anything ;P Anyway, here's my error:

> me.MCMedia.PresidentAssassination.Arena.Arena.getState(Arena.java:52)
>   17.11 03:29:02 [Server] INFO Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here's the Arena class..

```
public Arena(String name) {
    this.data = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();
    this.name = name;
    this.players = Integer.valueOf(Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getString("MaxUsers"));
    this.MinPlayers = Integer.valueOf(Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getString("MinUsers"));
    this.TaskID = TaskID;
    ConfigurationSection spawn = Main.getPlugin().getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Arenas."+name+".spawn");
    this.spawnPoint = LocationUtil.locationFromConfig(spawn, true);
    this.state = ArenaState.WAITING;
    this.playerManager = new PlayerManager(this);
}

public static ArenaState getState(Arena arena) {
    >>>> Line 52  <<<< return arena.state;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? You'd probably figure why `arena` doesn't get initialized properly.

Comment: You are missing code. `getState` is never called.

Comment: You're calling `getState` with a `null` argument. Post the code that is calling `getState` (and the code that computes the argument to the call).

Comment: public static void start(Arena arena){
  if((Arena.getState(arena) != ArenaState.STARTED)){
   Arena.setState(arena, ArenaState.COUNTING_DOWN);
   startSecondsarenacountdown(arena);
   return;
  }
  return;
 }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like instance of Arena being passed to static function is NULL.

Try removing static from "public static ArenaState getState()". I think it should be a instance level method. Anyways we have to pass an instance of Arena to this method.

Thanks.